# batch script copy only new files to destination

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I need some help with a batch script wherein the requirement is to copy only the new or modified files to the destiantion, at the destination once the files are read they are deleted but the souce contains the same file which need not be copied again. Only the new files or modified files must be copied.

To achieve this I created a set of 2 more folders wherein the source folder is synced to the destination in doing so a text file is created which mentions only the new files copied. Next the file is duplicated and the path is changed. further both the text files are read and put into an array.

the issue I am facing is copying from the source to the destination. Can someone help or  provide a better logic of doing this.

```
@echo off
robocopy C:\Users\ffernandes\rifath\  C:\Users\ffernandes\raes\  /e /z /copy:DAT /mt /z /xc /xn /xo /np > C:\Users\ffernandes\Logfile.txt

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  disabledelayedexpansion
@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr /C:"New File" "C:\Users\ffernandes\Logfile.txt" > "C:\Users\ffernandes\report.txt"

SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "tokens=3*" %%a IN (C:\Users\ffernandes\report.txt) DO ECHO(%%b)>"C:\Users\ffernandes\c.txt"

REM pushd "%userprofile%\Desktop"

copy C:\Users\ffernandes\c.txt  C:\Users\ffernandes\d.txt
set "search=C:\Users\ffernandes\rifath"
set "replace=C:\Users\ffernandes\francis"
set "textFile=C:\Users\ffernandes\d.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\ffernandes\c.txt) do (
    set /A count+=1
    set "array[!count!]=%%a"
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%count%) do echo !array[%%i]!  

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%b in (C:\Users\ffernandes\d.txt) do (
    set /B count+=1
    set "array1[!count!]=%%b"
)
for /L %%j in (1,1,%count%) do echo !array1[%%j]!
for /L %%j in (1,1,%count%) do (
    copy !array[%%j]!   !array1[%%j]!
)
```

Comment: would `xcopy /d sourcedir\* destinationdir\` do what you want?

Comment: I'd ask that you try and look into the `SetLocal` command, and try to determine why you are using it so extensively in your code, especially without an explicit `EndLocal` or implied `EndLocal`, _(`:EOF` / `Exit`)_.

Comment: way too complicated. Use the `Archive` attribute. Whenever Windows creates/modifies a file, it sets this attribute, so all you have to do, is to copy all files with the Archive attribute and unset the attribute for the source file. Both `xcopy` and `robocopy` have parameters to act accordingly (it's `/M` for both). See `xcopy /?`, `robocopy /?` (and `dir /?` and `attrib /?` for completeness)